# How to find a Bluetooth device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I have a Nokia Lumia 925 and all I want to do is to enumerate all Bluetooth devices in and get its signal strength in realtime. But with this .... Windows Phone SDK I never find any device at all.

I know exactly which device I am after and have modelled this in the manifest file:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity"/>
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile" />
    <m2:DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
      <m2:Device Id="vidpid:0421 0716">
        <m2:Function Type="usage:ffaa 0001" />
        <m2:Function Type="usage:ffee 0001" />
        <m2:Function Type="usage:ffee 0002" />
        <m2:Function Type="usage:ffee 0003" />
        <m2:Function Type="usage:ffee 0004" />
      </m2:Device>
    </m2:DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

and still there is nothing.

```
async void StartLoadingDevices()
{
    PeerFinder.AllowBluetooth = true;
    PeerFinder.AllowInfrastructure = false;
 //   PeerFinder.Role = PeerRole.Host;
    PeerFinder.AllowWiFiDirect = false;
    //PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:PAIRED"] = "";
    PeerFinder.Start();
    int Runs = 0;
    int Exceptions = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var devices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
            cList.Items.Clear();
            cLabel.Text = "Updating Run " + Runs++;
            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                cList.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}", device.DisplayName, device.ServiceName));
            }
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            cExCount.Text = (++Exceptions).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting Exceptions in *PeerFinder.Start* and *PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync* depending if I try to get all paired devices or not. 
My goal is to find a small lost bluetooth device which is covered by snow outside. But so far I cannot even get the list of devices to work. The WP8 APIs look crippled to me and support only very specific app use cases. The generic use cases seem to be reserved for the OS. If there is a WP8 native API I am fine with that as well.

I COULD dig device out of the snow but a more technical solution where I can get the approximate location with my phone would be much perferred.

Comment: It's important to find out what profiles the device supports, then check if they're supported by the phone as well?

Comment: This post http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.de/2014/02/ble-for-windows-81-part-i.html seems to use Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.GenericAccess)); which at least finds the device although reading data from it needs more research. But Peerfinder does not work. I have also tried Windows 8.1 Desktop with WSALookupServiceBegin and BluetoothFindFirstDevice which all were not working as well. It feels strange that the GUI can find it but the APIs which are supposed to be used for this are not able to find it.

Comment: I find the device now via DeviceInformation it would be nice to connect and disconnect to the device so I can measure the response time. But DeviceInformation looks more like a connectionless protocol where I can send commands to it. Is there an API to connect to a paired bluetooth device and to explicitely disconnect it so I can measure the connect time?